# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. In react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a react app to learn MUI opportunities and get this error in Browser:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`. Error: Element type is invalid:
> expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
> composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export
> your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
> up default and named imports.

Here is my App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import routes from './routes';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container mt-4">
        <Routes>
          {routes.map((route, index) => (
            <Route key={index} path={route.path} element={route.component} />
          ))}
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

routes:

```
import Blog from "./pages/Blog";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Team from "./pages/Team";

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home, exact: true }, // Use the component class/function, not JSX element
  { path: '/blog', component: Blog },
  { path: '/team', component: Team },
];

export default routes;
```

Navbar:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import HistoryDrawer from "./HistoryDrawer";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [openDrawer, setOpenDrawer] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();

  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setOpenDrawer(!openDrawer);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Button
            color="inherit"
            component={Link}
            to="/"
            selected={location.pathname === "/"}
          >
            Home
          </Button>
          <Button
            color="inherit"
            component={Link}
            to="/blog"
            selected={location.pathname === "/blog"}
          >
            Blog
          </Button>
          <Button
            color="inherit"
            component={Link}
            to="/team"
            selected={location.pathname === "/team"}
          >
            Team
          </Button>
          <Button
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            onClick={toggleDrawer}
          >
            History
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <HistoryDrawer toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer} openDrawer={openDrawer}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: <Routes>
          {routes.map((route, index) => (
            <Route key={index} path={route.path} element={route.component} />
          ))}
        </Routes>

Comment: can you try without a map function just refer the component directly and see if its working 

<Route key=1 path="/" element=Home exact=true />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue/discrepancy I see is that the `Route` component's `element` prop expects a `ReactNode` type, not a `ReactElement`. In other words, `element` takes JSX. I will assume the `Blog`, `Home`, and `Team` default export/imports are correct, but if there is an issue with any of them then check that they are all also default exported from their respective files.

You can either pass `routes` with JSX already:

```
import Blog from "./pages/Blog";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Team from "./pages/Team";

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: <Home />, },
  { path: '/blog', component: <Blog /> },
  { path: '/team', component: <Team /> },
];
```

Or render as JSX when mapping:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container mt-4">
        <Routes>
          {routes.map((route) => {
            const Component = route.component;
            return (
              <Route
                key={route.path}
                path={route.path}
                element={<Component />}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

You could simplify the `routes` code a bit as well by adhering the the [`RouteObject`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration) type:

```
import Blog from "./pages/Blog";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Team from "./pages/Team";

const routes = [
  { path: '/', elememt: <Home />, },
  { path: '/blog', element: <Blog /> },
  { path: '/team', element: <Team /> },
];
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container mt-4">
        <Routes>
          {routes.map((route, index) => (
            <Route key={index} {...route} />
          ))}
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Or use the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-routes) hook:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import routes from './routes';

const App = () => {
  const appRoutes = useRoutes(routes);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container mt-4">
        {appRoutes}
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```